# Find elements using css selector/xpath of Selenium Webdriver with Ruby

Tags: testing, css-selectors, selenium-webdriver, web-testing, ruby-test

I have recently started using Selenium to test an app having webviews. Well the code for my webview is:

```
<div class="class1 class2 class3 class4" style="padding: 4px;" id="_6bd7b91a-214c-4075-b7db-dcaa08155e1a"> 
    <span class="class5" style="font-weight: bold; text-decoration: underline;">This is TITLE</span> 
    <div class="class6" dd:contenttype="content_type1" dd:concept="TITLE" id="_1d8c4490-d0c1-42ed-a93e-e92ca570dd32">
     <div class="class7">
```

I am writing a re-usable code to find the element for automation testing. In the above code, element can be found using 2 ways, I can look for it based on `'dd:concept="TITLE"'` or through the text `"This is TITLE"`; but I could not find anything in Selenium using which I can find the element the way I want to.

I am using "find_element" to look for an element, but there is nothing to which I can pass `'dd:concept="TITLE"'` or `"This is TITLE"` as an arguement.

I tried - `driver.find_element(:css, "span.class5")` or `driver.find_element(:css, "div.class1 class2 class3 class4 span.class5")`

Is there anyway I can find the element on the webview using Selenium driver and some text as its arguement??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

FindElement(By.CssSelector("[dd:concept='TITLE']")) should work.

Ah, you're using ruby.

I did a bit of looking, you could try this:

find_element(:css, "[dd:concept='TITLE']")

Edit once again.

I would suggest escaping the : in the tag name dd:concept, like this:

find_element(:css, "[dd\:concept='TITLE']")

Comment: Thanks Richard!! But it didn't help me a lot. I am doing  $driver.find_element(By.CssSelector("[dd:concept='TITLE']")) and its giving me "NameError: uninitialized constant By
from (pry):3:in `block (3 levels) in <top (required)>'" error.

Comment: I guess the only arguments find_element is taking is one of these - (:class, :class_name, :css, :id, :link_text, :link, :partial_link_text, :name, :tag_name, :xpath)

Comment: I tried that way. Am getting "Selenium::WebDriver::Error::UnknownError: An unknown server-side error occurred while processing the command." error

Comment: With some google search I found I can use this - driver.find_element(:css, "div.ddsection ddrefreshable ddinsertfreetext ddremovable span.ddsectiondisplay"). But even this didn't work for me.

Comment: This worked for me. It wasn't working yesterday as for some reason I was not getting the required text inside the dom.