# Using css selector in Selenium Webdriver with Ruby

Tags: ruby, css-selectors, selenium-webdriver, web-testing, ruby-test

I have this code for which I am doing automation testing using ruby.

```
<div class="class1 class2 class3 class4" style="padding: 4px;" id="_d4b99a9f-d1c8-4587-94e2-5ee95ebf1f76"> 
    <span class="class5" style="font-weight: bold; text-decoration: underline;">This is new TITLE</span> 
    <div class="class6" dd:contenttype="TEST CONTENT TYPE" dd:concept="TITLE" id="_7cfd6eed-fa15-42b8-81af-d09bf3cd4460">
     <div class="class7"> 
      <div class="class8" dd:contenttype="TEST CONTENT" dd:entityid="0" dd:entityversion="0" id="_1c9125c4-b078-4017-a5ad-c48210e7090b"> 
       <div class="class9 class10" dd:btnfloatingstyle="top-right" dd:entitytexttype="resultval" id="_9c41159a-3a5b-4de1-87d2-e3361bd4d746" contenteditable="true"></div> 
      </div> 
     </div>
    </div> 
   </div>
```

I want to search the element using either 'This is new TITLE' or 'TITLE' for which I tried find_element with css selector and also with xpath but none seemed to work for me.

```
driver.find_element(:css, "span.class5") or `driver.find_element(:css, "div.class1 class2 class3 class4 span.class5")`
```

Nothing seemed to work for me. Am I missing something?

Comment: Is this question different than your previous one - [Find elements using Selenium Webdriver](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17932696/find-elements-using-selenium-webdriver)?

Comment: Just trying to be more specific with the question.

Comment: If you are clarifying the question, you should edit the existing one rather than creating a new one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes,you can do that using [`selenium-webdriver`](http://selenium.googlecode.com/git/docs/api/rb/index.html) and [`:xpath`](http://docs.seleniumhq.org/docs/03_webdriver.jsp#by-xpath). Take a look at the below example:

```
require 'selenium-webdriver'

driver = Selenium::WebDriver.for :firefox
driver.navigate.to "http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ruby_(programming_language)"

driver.find_element(:xpath,"//span[@class = 'mw-headline' and text() = 'Ruby 1.0' ]").tag_name
# => "span"
driver.find_element(:xpath,"//span[@class = 'mw-headline' and text() = 'Ruby 1.0' ]").text
# => "Ruby 1.0"
```

This example is fully equivalent to your `html` code. Now try to create your `xpath`,by taking the help of the above. You will get success.

Answer (score 0):

Use nokogiri gem

```
require 'nokogiri'

$page_html = Nokogiri::HTML.parse(browser.html)

$page_html.css("span.ddsectiondisplay").text
=>"This is new Title"
```

Or if you're just using watir.

```
browser.title
=>"title of page"
```